# Can i use server side blazor for production?

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-server-side

Yes, I know it is ready for production but I am scared if I use for production I may have some proxy problems or other problems. My plane is to start a blazor server-side project and deploy in IIS, do I need any setting changes in IIS and anyone of you used blazor server-side in production, did you face any problem while deploying?

Comment: "I am scared if I use for production I may have some proxy problems or other problems." Then wait for Blazor on WebAssembly.

Comment: @LexLi, do you think it's not the right time to start server-side blazor ?

Comment: I chose to close this question because it is subjective and opinions based. Your fear remains yours, while others might feel different. I was just commenting that Blazor on WebAssembly might be a better option, but you can feel scared too.

Comment: Running server side in production works well. Just remember geography to your users matters for latency. Also, take advantage of your hosting companies features e.g. Cloud flare has extra options to enable higher latency, worth the extra money.

Answer (score 5):

I don’t have reputation to comment. Server side Blazor is phenomenal for production. Many companies have been using it for a long time. Deployment is the same as any asp.net core app. Checkout  [www.csharpacademy.com](http://www.csharpacademy.com)

I’ve also been receiving more contact from companies interested in converting apps to Blazor serverside from asp.net and webforms.

A couple gotchas with server side Blazor:

1. If your server goes down even for a millisecond, every client is dead. They will need to refresh to get a new connection. This doesn’t happen often in today’s world, but results may vary depending on use-case
2. I’ve seen with csharpacademy that if you leave the webpage open in a mobile phone for hours in a tab, then come back to it after other tasks, the page is dead and refresh needs to occur.
3. UI latency is more noticeable for server side. If you have a server in The US and have clients in other countries, they may see more delay. Again, checkout the latency on csharpacademy. It’s hosted in the US and I notice 0 latency with majority of clicks/interactions.

One last comment,
If you’re unsure of whether to use server side or clientside, I’d encourage you to try and build your app with flexibility in mind. Create a razor component library and put all your components/logic in there so that you can share the lib between a clientside and a server side app.

Cheers!

Comment: I think your points there show exactly why it's not a good model for production. IMO opinion using a websocket to transmit every DOM interaction is a terrible idea and scaling websocket infra is hard.